# Tools for .NetCore / .NetStandard libraries obfuscation

Tags: .net-core, obfuscation, .net-standard, smartassembly

Currently we were using SmartAssembly from RedGate to obfuscate out .Net Framework based libraries and it worked just fine.

However, in the past months we started working on supporting .NetCore and .NetStandard to be able to scale our product and noticed that we cannot longer obfuscate the resulting libraries because SmartAssembly doesn't support it yet.

Dotfuscator from what I know, could do the job, however it's not taking care of the relationships between dependencies so it's not actually a full obfuscation.

What other tools is the community using to achieve this purpose? I'm interested in free and commercial tools as well.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "taking care of relationships..."? Perhaps you need to disable [library mode](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/obfuscation_overview.html#library-mode)? Also are using Community Edition or Pro? Pro Evaluations are available for free, and include access to our support team, who might be able to help. (Full disclosure: I work for PreEmptive Solutions.)

Comment: You could check out [SoftwareRecs.SE] (be sure to check the FAQ for what's on topic / how they like questions to be) for some help.

Comment: We used Crypto Obfuscator previously, but doesn't work well even with quirks when you run on Mac / Linux. Switched to the open source Obfuscar. Weird name but it works.